# Where Can I find info on advanced debugging using dbx on AIX?

Tags: debugging

Where Can I find info on advanced debugging using dbx on AIX, 
by advance i mean debugging threaded applications that call your shared library.
and i do not own the threaded applications..
but thy call my functions from shared  library(its like a plugin)..

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/systems/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/doc/genprogc/dbx_symbolic_debug.htm

http://delphiwww.cern.ch/~dellib/tutorial/node22.html